# internal call asp mvc method using the uri

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have two methods in asp mvc

```
methodA(myViewModel vm);
methodB();
```

myViewModel is

```
public class myViewModel
{
  public int someInt...
  public string someString...
}
```

So the uri is something like this.

..../MyController/MethodA?someInt=2&someString=oh%crap%20crap%20crap

Now, 
I am inside methodB and I need to call methodA.
I dont have the int and string but i hold the uri like this:

```
string s = "/MyController/MethodA?someInt=2&someString=oh%crap%20crap%20crap"
```

I can do a split but it is ugly (in reality I have more parameters )
Is three a way to internally call mvc method with the uri?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that a typo error? If you already have the url for `MethodA` then why not simply do a rediret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually dont need to do anything... have your controller actions look like

```
    public ActionResult TestA(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        ViewBag.SomeInt = vm.someint;
        ViewBag.SomeString = vm.somestring;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TestB()
    {
        ViewBag.UrlToCall = Url.Action("TestA", new { someint=2, somestring="Oh Crap Crap Crap"});

        return View();
    }
```

with a given ViewModel like

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int someint { get; set; }
    public string somestring { get; set; }
}
```

and the Model Binder will automatically split the url string and decode it when it stores the data received into the ViewModel that is expected when TestA(MyViewModel vm) is called.
If the data shall come from the URL just make sure you do NOT set [HTTPPOST] attribute to the action as that would have the model binder search for post data to bind to the model.

example Views for the above actions:

TestA.cs
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "TestA";
    }

```
<h2>TestA</h2>

<p>
    someint: @ViewBag.SomeInt
</p>
<p>
    somestring: @ViewBag.SomeString
</p>
```

TestB.cs
    @{
     ViewBag.Title = "TestB";
    }

```
<h2>TestB</h2>

<a href="@ViewBag.UrlToCall">Click Here To Call TestA</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. you used "new { someint=2, somestring="Oh Crap Crap Crap"}" i had them both as "MyController/MethodA?someInt=2&someString=oh%crap%20crap%20crap". this means that I have to do split or indexOf in test b in order to assign them . Is there a way to avoid it, since I have the full url.

Comment: There are several methods on Url.... that help you creating url strings .. the easiest way in creating a url is using such a method and add all parameters you want to pass in an anonymous object...
Basically all the URL method does is create a url string... so if you'd set ViewBag.UrlToCall = "MethodA?someInt=2&someString=oh%crap%20crap%20crap" ... that should work as well... just remove the 'myController' as by default mvc always creates linnks to the same controller

Comment: "several methods on Url" such as which?

Comment: go into your controller method, type 'Url.' and hit STRG+SPACE to get the intellisense collection of Url... there'd be Url.Action(...) Url.RouteUrl(...) or Url.HttpRouteUrl(...)

btw the url you have given in your example misses a 20... oh%crap should be oh%20crap ...

Answer (score 0):

If `methodA` and `methodB` are controller actions, then you have a code smell. Controller actions should not be called from within each other. If you have some logic that is relevant to both actions, move that out to another method that is not a controller action.

If you are trying to insert part of a page into a view that is called by other controller, you need to use Partial Action. Have a look on [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) for explanation. The article talks about MVC2, but the similar API is applicable in the MVC4

Comment: I dont see it as a code smell. sometimes the client calls methodA with parameters and sometimes to methodB with other. think of methodB as overloaded methodA. methodB also gets a saved uri call to methodA. now is there a way to use it without splitting and calling another method?